# IntelliJ Idea "could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I installed IntelliJ Idea and I had a few working Java projects already on my system, but when I open and run a program from these projects the above-mentioned error is shown. I am also unable to create any new Java classes in these projects. But when I made a new project through IntelliJ no problems occurred. The problem happens only with existing projects.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should mark the certain folder `java` (whose location is `src/main/java` 
 in project) as `sources`:

1. Right Click `java` folder
2. Mark Directory as
3. Sources Root

Image explanation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look like you were having a compilation issue, please check the configuration in the project settings/structure

1. Project: SDK and language level
2. Modules: src, target